# program not going to "if" statement

Tags: python, if-statement

In my program I have allowed the user to either get randomly generated attributes, or enter their own.

When the user enters a number larger than 20, or less than 0, it *should* tell the user that the number they have entered is too big or too small, but it doesn't.

Here is my code, mainly focusing on the part where I have said.

```
if random_var2 == "yes": #if yes
    c2strength = random.randrange(1,20) #randomly generated
    c2skill = random.randrange(1,20)

    print(character2 + ", your strength is: ", c2strength, " and your skill is: ", c2skill) #print out attributes
elif random_var2 == "no": #else
    c2strength = int(input("Enter Strength attribute. Between 1 and 20: ")) #user inputs attributes between 1 and 20
    c2skill = int(input("Enter Skill attribute. Between 1 and 20: "))

    if c2strength < 1 and c2strength > 20: #checks to see if it's in bounds #HERE
        print("Please enter an attribute that is between 1 and 20. ")
        var()
    else: #if it is
        pass
    if c2skill < 1 and c2skill > 20:
        print("Please enter an attribute that is between 1 and 20. ")
        var()
```

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: `if c2strength < 1 and c2strength > 20` <-- I don't know of any number that can be *both* less than `1` *and* greater than `20`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi When this happen, the world will end.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Or folded in any way...

Answer (score 6):

You want `or`, not `and`: either the variable can be less than 1, *or* greater than 20. Never both at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Both `if c2strength < 1 and c2strength > 20` and `if c2skill < 1 and c2skill > 20:`

will test both the condition and there is no  number less than 1 and greater than 20. So, change it `or` which will short-circuited when one condition is successful.

Snippet:

```
>>> -2 < 1 and -2 > 20
False
>>> -2 < 1 or -2 > 20
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in logic.. Please try this

```
    if c2strength < 1 or c2strength > 20: #checks to see if it's in bounds #HERE
        print("Please enter an attribute that is between 1 and 20. ")
        var()
    if c2skill < 1 or c2skill > 20:
        print("Please enter an attribute that is between 1 and 20. ")
        var()
```